# Can I keep Paladin Danse as a follower if I beat Fallout 4 with the Minutemen?

Tags: fallout-4

Basically I plan on finishing fallout 4 with the Minutemen, but I'm going to do this **without** being enemies with the Brotherhood Of Steel. If I complete the game this way, will Paladin Danse still be an available follower?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you will be able to.  I just did the same playthrough with the minutemen and both BoS and Railroad are alive and well.

I even did the brotherhood quests past blind betrayal and Danse is still a companion.

However, if you do end up destroying the BoS at any point, even after blind betrayal, Danse will no longer become available as a companion.